# NetBeans - JavaFX Error / Maven execution failed?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

whenever I try to run an fx application in netbeans on my Mac it results in the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project PhysCal: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Rerun it as suggested to get the full stack trace, and post the stack trace in the question

Comment: Also, upgrade to the current version of `javafx-maven-plugin`.